# Listen for multiple response produced by one HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

Our backend (rails) needs to communicate with some 3rd party service (we don't have control over it). All the communication with this service has to be done using a single persistent HTTP connection.

Being `->` a request and `<-` a response form the server, this is the current flow:

```
-> Login
<- Ok
-> Subscribe
<- Ok
<- Data
<- Data
<- Data
...
<- Data
```

Once subscription is done the server starts to send some data from time to time.  Those are real-time updates that we have to handle. The problem is that we couldn't find a proper way of dealing with this.

`Subscribe`'s response header are pretty simple

```
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 183
Content-Type → text/xml
```

I looked at several gems that implements HTTP persistent connections but none of them seems to be able to handle this scenario.

Do you know some gem that can handle something like this? Otherwise, I don't want to reinvent the wheel implementing an HTTP client from scratch, so the best scenario would be to integrate this feature on an existent solution. Any idea on how should I proceed?

Comment: Do you mean that server 'pushes' new responses without a request? Or that all is a single long request (then why there's `content-length`?)

Comment: You can try using pure ruby sockets: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html

Comment: Exactly, server starts pushing responses.

Comment: @Axxiss - HTTP protocole is an application layer protocol based on request-response schema, you cannot do what you want using http. You need to go level down and use TCP protocol. Ruby sockets library is great for that - you can handle login with http, and on success open up a socket.

Comment: What is this 3rd party service? Maybe looking at their docs will help clear it out?

Comment: what you're describing doesn't sound like simply persistent HTTP connections with keep-alive.  That's probably why the gems you find that support persistent HTTP connections don't seem suitable, because what you need is something else. From your description, it's not entirely clear what it is though. You need more clear specs from/about the server's requirements and what technology it's using exactly.

Comment: @jrochkind we're totally agree that this isn't the normal persistent HTTP workflow. They require us to exchange all the messages on a single connection. So login and subscribe request has to be sent using the same socket. Then still on the same connection we have to listen to push responses from server.

Comment: Is it "Server-Sent Events"? I don't think so. It's clearly not WebSockets. It's not "Long Polling."  It sounds to me like it may not actually be HTTP at all, it's something they've invented that looks a lot like HTTP, but isn't going to work with standard HTTP clients. It might be useful to see if they have any examples of a client in _any_ language; how they have a client that works in a non-ruby language may have clues for how to approach it in ruby.

Comment: We just found out that is very similar to twitter streaming API, we're taking a look to Event Machine, as it seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up building a solution on top of [eventmachine](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine). EM allow us to receive events every time a piece of data is received on the connection. Then data is passed to [http_parser.rb](https://github.com/tmm1/http_parser.rb) to parse incoming http messages and finally we enqueue the message on sidekiq.